# Tag synonym request: [scrollviewer] -> [scrollview]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I found on Stack Overflow two similar tags [scrollviewer](/questions/tagged/scrollviewer) and [scrollview](/questions/tagged/scrollview). Both have same meaning. So, I suggest to make [scrollviewer](/questions/tagged/scrollviewer) a synonym for [scrollview](/questions/tagged/scrollview).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about this one... [ScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.aspx) is a class in .NET 4, while [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) is an Android class. While the classes might have similar functionality and names, they serve two different platforms, and provided the tags are used appropriately, the meaning can be made distinct.

Note that there is also [uiscrollview](/questions/tagged/uiscrollview), which is relevant to iOS, and there are probably several other classes with similar names on other platforms.

Comment: Agreed. Not sure who named the "scrollviewer" class anyway. :-)